# Using SeleniumDriver to pull data from multiple spans

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So I have multiple webpages that have essentially the main part a bunch of `<span>` tags. In these the `id` for the `span` is random.

The basic page structure is as follows:

```
<pre>
    <span id = "abcdf">
        <a href="">x</a>
        <span title="1">
        <a href="">random text</a>
        <a href="">random text</a>
    </span>
    ... Repeat ...
    <span id = "awfaf">
        <a href="">x</a>
        <span title="127">
        <a href="">random text</a>
        <a href="">random text</a>
    </span>
</pre>
```

The id is always random, and the title for the span is always an integer. (It increases so 1-128 on page one, 129 to 256 on page two. Etc.)

What I would like to do is pull the `id` of the span, and then the two columns/text in the second and third `href` of each page.

I'm not sure how to go around to doing this in a repeatable way and simply need an idea for the logic, that is which elements to pull and such when going through the pages.

Comment: you need a parser, beautifulsoup4 might help, you can write your own, many ways of doing this, can you show some effort on what you've tried and what went wrong?

Comment: @MooingRawr I honestly have no idea where to even approach the problem, since the ID's are different.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is one of the way to get the required data using Java:

```
List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> textList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> textList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i=1;
        while (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//pre/span[" + i + "]")).size() != 0) {

            idList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre/span[" + i + "]")).getAttribute("id"));
            textList1.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre/span[" + i + "]/a[2]")).getText());
            textList2.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre/span[" + i + "]/a[3]")).getText());
            i++;
        }
```

Above code can be executed for each page.

Comment: How would I do this in python? Which is how it's tagged.

Comment: I know Python' is tagged in your question. However, based on your statement: `I'm not sure how to go around to doing this in a repeatable way and simply need an idea for the logic` I just provided the logic. Let me know, if you have any issues in understanding the logic.

Comment: Well the first issue I have is you have i as an integer. But if I have say page 53, it won't start at element #1? and how is it supposed to get [i] as string, if i is an integer? shouldn't it have string conecation

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I missed to concatenate the i with xpath string. I have corrected that in my response. Regarding your query about page 53, for each page the first occurrence will start with index 1. Hence, for each page we can traverse `span` 1 to n. Once, we have no more `span` on the current page, we need to move to next page and repeat the same logic. Please let me know, if you have any further queries. I will try to implement same logic in python and share with you.

Comment: Figured it out. Accepted.